# Persistência e leitura de dados do Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

gostaria de ter uma estrutura de dados no realtime database do Firebase parecido com isso:

```
{

  "codigo": "01",

  "Data": "1234567890",

  "usuario": "{codigo : 01, nome : Rafael}"

}
```

tenho a classe:

```
class Consulta {
   String codigo;
   Long data;
   Usuario usuario;
}
```

a classe usuário tem mais atributos, mas só quero salvar esses que estão no JSON.

Como eu salvo esses valores pra ficar dessa estrutura? Como eu leio esses valores?

Caso usuário fosse um Arraylist, como ficaria essa leitura e escrita?

Answer (score 1):

Pra salvar desse jeito, você vai ter que ter um objeto que contenha os valores código, data e usuário. O usuário será um objeto que deverá ser transformado em JSON (string) antes de ser enviado para o firebase.
Mas não recomendo fazer isso pois, se voce enviar o objeto com esses dois atributos+o objeto usuário, o firebase cuida sozinho de criar a árvore de dados em json.
Para excluir atributos de serem salvos, usa o annotation @Exclude em cima de cada atributo que você quer que não salva no firebase.

Comment: Obrigado, mas quando eu mando salvar um usuário em alguma outra tela, eu quero que salva todos os atributos. E colocando anotação vai bloquear isso. Mas o foco dá pergunta é como salvar e como ler e transformar a resposta em um objeto da classe consulta.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode adicionar um usuário com **setValue()** da seguinte maneira:
Usando os dados da sua classe acima, ficaria assim:

```
private void novaConsulta(int codigo, DateTime data, Usuario usuario) {
    Usuario usuario= Usuario User(codigo, nome);

    mDatabase.child("usuarios").child(codigo).setValue(usuario);
}
```

Assumindo que vc já tenha essa estrutura consulta e usuarios no firebase